# How to overwrite element style so it cannot be changed?

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

I am writing a Chrome extension and I need to make all of the elements' position relative. I've tried to add `position: relative !important;` to `body`'s style. However when I am scrolling the page, some JS inside the page changes the style of the body child element to `position: fixed` and it becomes fixed. I don't want this to happen, so, is there any way to make all of the elements relative once and for all?

I've tested this behaviour on this page: http://sandesh.epapr.in/709519/Ahmedabad/02-02-2016#dual/4/3, I want the header and the footer to be not fixed, but no luck.

Comment: Best you can do is watch the element's position value (on a `setInterval` perhaps) and set it back to `relative` whenever it changes.

Comment: (Though that does of course carry the risk of endless loops if the javascript you're fighting against is doing the same thing!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, someone could always change the style with more specificity or with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following order, while **Style sheets** / **Style rules** are considered:

1. Declarations marked as **!important**
2. Declarations in **author's style sheet** (provided by website)

   > specificity = Concatenating a & b & c with the following order and weights:
   >   a = 100 * ( number of ID attributes in the selector )
   >   b = 10 * ( number of Class attributes (or Pseudo-classes) in the selector )
   >   c = 1 * ( number of tag names (or Pseudo-elements) in the selector )

   - **Higher specificity** (first)

     - Rules in **main style sheet**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
     - Rules in **imported style sheets**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
   - **Lower specificity** (next)

     - Rules in **main style sheet**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
     - Rules in **imported style sheets**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
3. Declarations in [**user style sheet**](http://dbaron.org/css/user/)
   [ Like part 2 ]
4. Declarations in **User-Agent style sheet** (provided by browser)
   [ Like part 2 ]

Answer (score 0):

You could unbind all the jQuery that's attached to the document scrolling.  That would prevent the site's javascript from changing the CSS to begin with.

```
$(document).unbind('scroll');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chrome inspect window to see what javascript files are being executed on your page and what the change to your style, once you identify what function is doing this then you can edit the function todisable this change.